# Nginx reverse proxy falling after update Docker to 1.13

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-swarm

i'm having a connection timed out issue with nginx reverse proxy since yesterday when we updated docker to version 1.13

here is the error log from Nginx

```
upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.255.0.3, server: 10.1.232.220, request: "GET /Microservice/microservices HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.255.0.10:8765/Microservice/microservices", host: "10.1.232.220"
```

The nginx is a service inside a docker swarm where also is the backend that i'm trying to call, i make a ping from the nginx container to the ip showing in the error log and there is no problem, any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Are you able to curl or wget the requested url from a container? A ping doesn't indicate that the target container is serving content.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply, i try the wget with the ip http://10.255.0.10:8765/Microservice/microservices from the error log and i get connection timed out, but when i try it with the ip of a host in the swarm i get the response

Comment: Looks like you're pointing to the wrong IP. Can you describe how you've configured your proxy, and what the various IP's are that work and don't work?

Comment: i'm using consul template for load balancing my backend, this is the nginx configuration that results from consul: upstream Microservice {
  least_conn; 
  server 10.255.0.10:8765;
  server 10.255.0.16:8765;
}   
} 
server {                                 
  listen              80;
  server_name         10.1.232.240;   
  location /Microservice/ {
        proxy_pass http://Microservice;
  }
}, when i try with the ip 10.1.232.240:8765 it works fine (that's the ip of the docker swarm manager )